# Replace 0's in column with another value from different column - R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am working on creating a column called Quantity that holds the number of stocks either long or short in my portfolio.

- The positions() fxn I have initialized returns a tibble (48 x 6):
  Instrument Symbol, averagePrice, longQuantity, shortQuantity, marketValue, assetType
- [Positions function returns these columns [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTIsx.png)

I have written a function to assign the individual tickers a long or short factor to keep track of which stocks are long/short.

```
positions() %>%

mutate(long.short =  factor(ifelse(positions()$longQuantity > 0, "long", "short")))
```

.

I am running into an error with my for loop which iterates through the df and will merge the columns into one, replacing values of 0 in longQuantity with the values from shortQuantity.
`

```
    positions() %>%
        mutate(long.short =  factor(ifelse(positions()$longQuantity > 0, "long", "short"))) %>%
    #Code to merge long and short quantity into one column
        for(i in 1:nrow(positions())){
                if(positions()$longQuantity[i] == 0){
                        replace(positions()$longQuantity, i, positions()$shortQuantity[i])      
                } 
        }

`
```

- This is the error,

  Error in for (. in i) 1:nrow(positions()) :

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated thanks!
4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3

Comment: Please give a small sample of data, e.g., `dput(positions()[1:10, 1:5])` for the first 10 rows of the first 5 columns - choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: R is vectorized, so you shouldn't need a loop here. It may be as simple as `positions() %>% mutate(longQuantity = ifelse(longQuantity == 0, shortQuantity, longQuantity))`, but it's hard to tell without seeing data and your desired result.

Comment: Also, don't use `data$column` inside `dplyr` functions - they expect you to just use column names. It also seems terribly inefficient to call your `positions()` function so many times - but if you stop using `positions()$column` every time you reference a column that should take care of that.

Comment: There is a photo linked to the, "[Positions function returns these columns 1" in the questions. Joining those two columns together is the aim of the for loop, but you're right i don think i DO need one.

Comment: Was able to solve with your suggested line, thanks for showing me that. Also for the dplyr tips, just getting to grips with it!